# SharePoint 2013 View Filter using CAML and User ID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, caml

To start off, I would like to thank anyone in advance for the help. I am using SharePoint 2013, SharePoint designer 2013, and attempting to create a new filtered view...

I have a list of entries that has a column which contains multiple username's.

> Ex: Username1 Username2 Username3

What I'm looking to do is filter the view based upon whether or not the UserIDs column contains the currently logged in user. I've found a couple of walk throughs on this issue but none seem to work (I can't seem to make it do so). I believe the reason it does not work is because our SharePoint environment adds a 'salt' to the beginning of each username it pulls.

> Ex: i:0#.w|DomainName\UserName

As you can tell in the column above, I'm substringing all of the Salt/Domain information out. Would anyone happen to know if this is possible? 
If so, do I need to use Jscript to pull the username before I filter?

Below are three more examples of what I've tried....

```
<Where>
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name='UserIDs' />
<Value Type='User'>System Account</Value>
</Contains>
</Where>
```

---

```
<Where>
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name='UserIDs' LookupId='True'  />
<Value Type='User'>1073741823</Value>
</Contains>
</Where>
```

---

```
<Where>
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name='UserIDs'/>
<Value Type='User'><UserID/></Value>
</Contains>
</Where>
```

Comment: Is the username column of type Person or Text?

Comment: It's a text column. It holds only usernames and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I've used these two before and they worked:

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name="UserIDs" LookupId="TRUE" />
   <Value Type="User">1073741823</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>

<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="UserIDs" LookupId="TRUE" />
    <Value Type="Lookup">1073741823</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: I will give that **<Value Type="Lookup">** a go. Do you have any documentation in the differences between the two?

Comment: https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/caml-query-lookup-field-by-id-not-by-value/

also, i believe "True" should be all caps. i will edit my answer.